# why don't I get any fired converter?

Tags: silverlight

I have radio button and I want to define binding between the radio button IsChecked state and the visibility some stackpanel so I wrote this convert method:

```
 public class RadioBtnState2Visible : IValueConverter
{
    // RadioBtn start => Visible / Hide
    public object Convert( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture )
    {
        if( value == null )
            return Visibility.Collapsed;

        bool visibility = false;
        bool.TryParse( value.ToString(), out visibility );

        return visibility ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;

    }

    public object ConvertBack( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture )
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
        //return ( ( Visibility )value ) == Visibility.Visible ? true : false;
    }
}
```

The xaml is

```
<local:PageEx.Resources>   
     <local:RadioBtnState2Visible x:Key="Convert" /> 
</local:PageEx.Resources> 

<RadioButton x:Name="MyRadioBtn1" GroupName="group1" /> 
<RadioButton x:Name="MyRadioBtn2" GroupName="group1" />  

<StackPanel Visibility="{Binding ElementName=MyRadioBtn1, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource Convert}}" />
```

Now, I dont see any convert fire - i dont see that the application stops on the breakpoint that i set on the first line of the convert method.

Comment: Do you see any binding error in the output window when you run this in debug?

Comment: Im sorry about the -1 . it was a honest mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a duplicate of your previous question, already answered. Here is the answer again:

I got your code working in a test project with one minor change. I made the converter a page resource with the following syntax:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:RadioBtnState2Visible x:Key="Convert" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

I should also mention that I had to actually put something in the stackpanel as well to see the change as by default it collapses to nothing :) I assume you actually have content in your real stackpanel.

---

**Just to explain what is happening here. By adding "local:" to the resource declaration you are actually enclosing an instance of a Resource, and not changing the current resource. Referencing it by "Convert" does not work because it cannot find the resource where it expects to find it.**

Comment: Please read the code. the resource is right. i using the 'convert'

Comment: @Yanshof: I did not say there reference name was wrong. I said the declaration of the resource was wrong. Take our the "local:" part. Thanks for the negative when I went to the trouble of actually building and fixing an actual test project. Try reading my answer again.

Comment: my stackpanel is full of controls - i just copy to here the stackpanel header.

Comment: @Yanshof: Please address this "local:UserControl.Resources" issue.  It that is a typeo in your question? If so correct it, if not, how is it you have a class called in `UserControl` in your own project?  Its difficult to move forward to help you with this oddity still hanging about.

Comment: The resource is PageEx ( the pageEx base class is Page ).

Comment: Hitech Magic - Im sorry about the -1 . it was a honest mistake ( press on the wrong arrow on the screen.

Comment: Sorry again - the resource that i want to use is exist on PageEx object.

Comment: @Yanshof: No problem. Please provide more XAML in future questions. Then mistakes are easier to spot in context. Fragments make it hard to see what is going on. Glad you got it working now anyway.

Answer (score 0):

FYI there is BooleanToVisibilityConverter converter available already:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter1" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Not in Silverlight there isn't.